# image breaking out of floated div on resize

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains two divs which are both floated left so that they sit side by side. In the right div is a youtube video and a picture. When I resize the page the picture and video both flow out of the containing floated div instead of that div just dropping below the other. How can I stop this?

Comment: if you have try please share your html and css in jsfiddle?

Comment: Can you add your code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add an extra div styled with `clear:both` or use a clearfix class like [here](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

I personally recommend using a clearfix class.

Comment: Old answer but solved the issue for me. Here is a JSFiddle; comment out `<div id="details_clear"></div>` and reload / resize the page to see the issue. (On small view sizes, the images were breaking out of their containing DIV.) https://jsfiddle.net/vstuart/fyzue14b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery,
Onload with the jquery, measure the width of the parent div and assign it to the child image or video.