# IMG breaking out of DIV on resize

Tags: html, css

I have an image in a DIV at the top, as a header. There is another DIV with text to the right side of it. When I resize my Google Chrome browser to a certain size, the image breaks out of the div and goes into the text DIV. I want to know how I can force the image to stay the same size as the DIV when it wants to break out and not mix with other elements.

Comment: My issue: on small view sizes, the images were breaking out of their containing DIV. Accepted answer here indicated the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17947339/1904943 | This JSFiddle demonstrates that solution (comment out <div id="details_clear"></div> and reload / resize the page to see the issue) https://jsfiddle.net/vstuart/fyzue14b/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a width of 100% for the image to make it fit the div:

```
div {
    width: 40% /* or whatever */
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The max-width:100% made it work for me. Now when I resize the browser window, the image stays in the div :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question enough, although it would help to see some code. Here is something that works for me though.

```
img.resize {
    width:100px;
    height: auto;
}
```